# Python: Sending an Email including CC

Tags: python, email, smtplib

```
msg['From'] = email_from

msg['To'] = "aaa@abc.com"

msg['Cc'] = "bbb@abc.com, ccc@abc.com"

...


server.sendmail(email_from, "aaa@abc.com, bbb@abc.com, ccc@abc.com", msg.as_string())
```

I sent an email through above code. (Those three emails are mine, so I can check up all of them)

I see an email that I sent through python code in the inbox of "aaa", and there clearly shows that two other emails ("bbb" and "ccc") on the CC list.

However, I cannot find the email either "bbb"/"ccc" inbox. I want to figure out what is happening behind and why the email is not sent to those two emails.

Comment: please format your code properly.

Comment: Check your SMTP server logs.  Are you seeing successful deliveries to the MX for the cc addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send the email the to and cc emails must be in an array. So the correct form of the command should be like this:

server.sendemail(email_from, ["aaa@abc.com","bbb@abc.com","ccc@qbc.com"], msg.as_string())